# Issue creating custom view class : Android

Tags: android, animation, view

Ok, this question might sound pretty naive but I've never been able to find an answer from reliable source for this questions.

I've a complex view that I'm inflating from XML. I also have lots of actions and properties associated with that view. Also, the view is a part of complex list. Currently I'm inflating views from XML and doing all operations in `MainActivity`. However, that kind of complicated my code and isn't a fair design strategy.

So, I tried googling for encapsulating the inflated view inside a View class and came up with the design below:

```
public class FeedView extends LinearLayout {

    Feed feed;
    SlideAnimation inAnimation;
    SlideAnimation outAnimation;
    View view;
    boolean isViewExpanded;
    List<Article> articleList;

    public boolean isViewExpanded() {
        return isViewExpanded;
    }

    public void setViewExpanded(boolean isViewExpanded) {
        this.isViewExpanded = isViewExpanded;
    }

    public FeedView(Context context, Feed feed) {
        super(context);
        this.feed = feed;
        isViewExpanded = false;
        init();

    }

    private void init() {
        LayoutInflater mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.collapsed_feed, this, true);

        TextView feed_name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.feed_name);
        feed_name.setText(feed.feed_name);

        ImageView feed_image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.feed_image);
        String image_url = feed.feed_image_url;
        ImageLoaderForFeeds imgLoaderForFeeds = new ImageLoaderForFeeds(getContext());

        imgLoaderForFeeds.DisplayImage(image_url, feed_image);

        if (feed.isFavourite)
        {
            TextView tv_add_to_favourite = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_add_to_favourite);
            ImageView iv_add_to_favourite = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.img_add_to_favourite);
            tv_add_to_favourite.setText(R.string.remove_from_favourite);
            tv_add_to_favourite.setTextColor(Color.GRAY);
            iv_add_to_favourite.setSelected(true);
        }

        RelativeLayout favourite_bar = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.add_to_favourite);
        String tag = "FAVOURITE";
        favourite_bar.setTag(tag);
    }

    public void toggleView(int length) {
        if (!isViewExpanded)
            expandView(length);
        else
            collapseView();
    }


    private void expandView(int length) {

    }

    public void collapseView() {

    }

    public List<Article> getArticleList() {
        return articleList;
    }

    public void setArticleList(List<Article> articleList) {
        this.articleList = articleList;
    }

    private void showArticleList() {

    }
```

**Question :** Am I designing this class properly? Is it alright to inflate XML inside a view class like I'm doing. If yes, am I doing it at the right place? Also suggest if ther is a better design to achieve this !

I also had some issues when I came up with this class though I guess it might be linked to previous question.

**Issue #1:** Sometimes I've issue while finding FeedView using`findViewById()` and it returns null though the id is set properly.

**Issue #2:** On animating FeedView class, it responds unexpectedly and comes up with few dimension defect. No idea why !

Comment: what you have done for creating custom view and inflating xml layout is fine to work.

Comment: yup, this is how it's done.  Might want to add another constructor with an attributeset so it can be inflated from xml, but that is a nice to have and not necessary.  Inflating within a view class works, and is consistent with encapsulation.

Comment: @edthethird Do you any idea regarding the issues that I talked about ?